# SQL one row output with count()

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS GesamtanzahlMitarbeiter, 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM EMP WHERE HIREDATE LIKE '%80') AS "1980", 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM EMP WHERE HIREDATE LIKE '%81') AS "1981", 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM EMP WHERE HIREDATE LIKE '%82') AS "1982", 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM EMP WHERE HIREDATE LIKE '%83') AS "1983"  
FROM EMP 
GROUP BY DEPTNO;
```

And I get this Output:

```
GESAMTANZAHLMITARBEITER       1980       1981       1982       1983
----------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
                      6          1         10          2          1
                      5          1         10          2          1
                      3          1         10          2          1
```

Now the Point is, that I don't want to group by deptno. I want to Group them all and count all the "GESAMTANZAHLMITARBEITER" like this:

```
GESAMTANZAHLMITARBEITER       1980       1981       1982       1983
----------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
                     14          1         10          2          1
```

But I cannot GROUP BY * or something..
A workaround would be to give them all a new attribute with the same value and group by that attribute, but thats just not right.

I have no Idea how to do that...

Comment: Just remove grouping..

Comment: Then I get error messages, it seems like it needs to be grouped if you use count()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a conditional aggregation, add `case` in the `SUM`

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as GesamtanzahlMitarbeiter,
    SUM(CASE WHEN HIREDATE LIKE '%80'THEN 1 ELSE 0) as "1980",
    SUM(CASE WHEN HIREDATE LIKE '%81'THEN 1 ELSE 0) as "1981",
    SUM(CASE WHEN HIREDATE LIKE '%82'THEN 1 ELSE 0) as "1982",
    SUM(CASE WHEN HIREDATE LIKE '%83'THEN 1 ELSE 0) as "1983"
FROM EMP
```

**NOTE:** If you add `GROUP BY` to this query you will get `COUNT(*)` by each `emp` In your previous query you get `COUNT(*)` for all table in each row.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it wouldn't work out with Group By that way.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count` without `group by` like this:

```
SELECT
(SELECT Count(*) FROM EMP) AS GesamtanzahlMitarbeiter, 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM EMP WHERE HIREDATE LIKE '%80') AS "1980", 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM EMP WHERE HIREDATE LIKE '%81') AS "1981", 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM EMP WHERE HIREDATE LIKE '%82') AS "1982", 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM EMP WHERE HIREDATE LIKE '%83') AS "1983"  
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this (assumes a reasonably recent version of Oracle):

```
with pivot_data as
     ( select to_number(to_char(hiredate,'YYYY')) as year
       from   emp )
   , pivotted as
     ( select *
       from   pivot_data pd
       pivot  ( count(year) for year in (1980, 1981, 1982, 1983) ) )
   , totals as
     ( select count(*) as GesamtanzahlMitarbeiter from pivot_data )
select t.GesamtanzahlMitarbeiter
     , p.*
from   pivotted p cross join totals t;
```